# How to change old revision and merge into tip?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

As said in the title, here is a graph to demonstrate what I want to achieve:

[image]

The newest is revision 3, and I went back to revision 2 to fix something, which is commited to revision 2a, and then I need to merge 2a and 3.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case if I want to merge revision X into revision Y.  I just have to do:

```
hg update Y
hg merge X
```

So if you want to merge 2A into 3 yielding 4 you'd do:

```
hg update 3
hg merge 2A
```

If that doesn't cover your needs you'll have to rephrase the question.